# How to enable the haptic feedback (vibration) within a WebView?

Tags: android, webview, accessibility, vibration

I've been having a look to the built-in haptic feedback you can enable trough the *KickBack* setting on the Accesibility menu. It works like I expected on most of UI elements.

For those who are not aware of what haptic feedback is, it's very simple, just vibrate slighty as the user presses any button/key/field.

Well, my problem is about enabling that feaure on a WebView interface. I made sure to enable it by calling `WebView.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(true)`, but it wouldn't work. I also tried using the native Android Web Browser, but the haptic feedback is not enabled on there either.

I was wondering if someone has some tip on how to manually set that feedback for the WebView, cause I've been having a look to the API, and can't get any idea.

PD: I'm developing for FroYo on a Nexus One with 2.2.1.

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible since the default WebView control is not accessible. This will be fixed in Android 3.0, according to [this blog entry](http://eyes-free.blogspot.com/) If you must get accessibility working for web content displayed in your app take a look at [IDEAL Web Reader](http://www.apps4android.org/?p=1232) It's open source so you may be able to use some of their code or ideas in your own application.